# sequence and its mean converge to different limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

can some one give me an example of a sequence of numbers vn such that its mean tends to a limit, but vn does not.

I was thinking about an uniform function or something like that, but I am not quite sure.

Comment: How about $v_n=(-1)^n$?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $u_n = (-1)^n$ is such an example, since you can check that
$$
\lim \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^n = 0,
$$

while $u_n$ does not have a limit. You may want to take a look at "Cesaro sums".

Comment: Note:  that limit is not $\frac 12$.  There is no $n$ for which the mean is $>0$ and, of course, the mean $=0$ for all even $n$.

Comment: @lulu My bad, I'll correct it. I was think about the partial sums of $\sum_{n \ge 1} (-1)^n$.

Comment: Worth remarking:  Cesaro summation works with the mean of the partial sums.  In your case, the partial sums are $\{-1,0,-1,0,-1,\cdots\}$ so the relevant limit would be $-\frac 12$, but that's not what the OP was asking about.